# Preferred way to break a forEach method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was just using `forEach` method in JavaScript to sum up all the elements in an array. Suddenly felt the need to break out of the loop on certain conditions, for example putting a limit on the sum to be calculated.
I have come up with the following solution. Point me if I am wrong.

small edit to this

```
function foreach(a) {
 var sum = 0;
 var breakException = {error:"stop it"};
 try {
    a.forEach(function (v) {
        sum += v;
        console.log(sum);
        if(sum>5) throw breakException.error;
    });
    return sum;
}
catch(e) {
    if(e!=breakException){
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the try-catch?

Comment: just made a small edit.... not a good move...but working..kindof

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not supposed to break. If you 'd like to break a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)-like loop, try [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fevery) or [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsome), which let you break out of the loop.

A possible way to re-write your code could be

```
var sum = 0;

yourArray.some(function (item) {
    if (sum > 5) {
        return true;
    }
    sum += item;
});
```

Comment: @AmitJoki well you can use `.some()` as if it were a `.forEach()` except you have to keep returning `false` for it to continue. As soon as the callback returns `true`, the iterations stops. The return value can be ignored. (I guess if you don't `explicitly` return `false` and just let the return value be `undefined`, that works too.)

Comment: @Pointy got it. That's why I removed my first comment.

Comment: i know there are alternatives...... but if we are fetching large number of records in an array and suppose there is a forEach loop, then what will be the new way to break it at some point

Comment: @optimus, you seem to be missing the point. If you want to break out of a loop you would _need_ to use one the alternative given in the answers here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't break out of a `forEach`. Just use a normal loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < a; i++){
   sum += a[i];
   if(sum > 5) break;
}
```

Comment: i know i can use a for loop. That was just to demonstrate that If we can come out of forEach or not.

Comment: Btw, you can break out of a `forEach` loop by `throw`ing :-)

Comment: @Bergi that would be like jail-breaking :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code seems a little silly.

Your try/catch block is useless, as you don't ever throw an error for the catch block to catch, then re-throw (?) and you don't need to `alert("break");` to stop a script.

You can't break out of a `forEach` loop anyway, I think you'd just want to use a normal for loop:

```js
function sum(list){
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++){
    sum += list[i];
    if (sum > 5){
      break;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```